# Swap background for piechart diagram, why only run once ? can't figure out why

Tags: jquery, background, swap, pie-chart

The script :

```
$("#listchart li").mouseover(function()
{
        if($(this).hasClass('one'))
    {
            $('#piechart').addClass('piechart-one').removeClass(className);
        }

        if($(this).hasClass('two'))
    {
            $('#piechart').addClass('piechart-two').removeClass(className);
        }
        if($(this).hasClass('three'))
    {
            $('#piechart').addClass('piechart-three').removeClass(className);
        }

        if($(this).hasClass('four'))
    {
            $('#piechart').addClass('piechart-four').removeClass(className);
        }
});
```

Sorry, the code is such a noob manual labor, I just can't figure out how to go to next 'li' in jQuery & call specific CSS class. I'd really really really appreciate it if you guys can show me the proper way to do this.

The HTML :

```
<div id="piechart" class="piechart-one">

<div id="listchart">
<ul>
<li class="one"><a href="">SubTitle-1</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="">SubTitle-2</a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="">SubTitle-3</a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="">SubTitle-4</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

So default class being called when the page opened at first place is 'piechart-one'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

( If I understood your question well: )

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/San95/)

code used:

```
$('#listchart li').hover(function(){

    var takeClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#piechart').attr('class', 'piechart-'+takeClass );

},function(){
    $('#piechart').attr('class', 'piechart-one' );
});
```

With `li` color change

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/San95/1/)

code:

```
$('#listchart li').hover(function(){

    var takeClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#piechart').attr('class', 'piechart-'+takeClass );
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

},function(){
    $('#piechart').attr('class', 'piechart-one' );
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Just add a CSS class **.active** and in your jQuery toggle the class. Look at the demo.

But I'll do it a bit more fancy:

### [DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/San95/2/)

Comment: my goodness, that is much simpler ! thank you !! quick additional question, i'd like to set the <li> Subtitle </li> 'active' when its being hovered to do color font change. How to accomplish that ?

Comment: thanks roXon. I've added <a href="">Subtitle</a> in my original post if that even gonna help ?

Comment: Ignore my a href comment, I got confuse :) Anyway roXon, i just tried your code. It's working, thanks for that! But the 'active' stays there even though I hover the other subtitle.

Comment: Sorry maybe i should explain it clear. So when people mouseOver Subtitle-1, it will active then when they mouseOver Subtitle-2, subtitle-1 has to back to normal font color and subtitle-2.active. Is that make sense ?

Comment: roXon, yes it works well ! :) But when your move your mouse OUTSIDE the link, the font-color back to normal. So I'd like to have the "active" remain active eventhough the mouse is outside that <li></li> unless mouseOver the OTHER <li>subtitle</li>. I hope I don't demand too much lol...I'm learning at the same time :) thanks a bunch in advance for the help !

Comment: never mind roXon, i've just figure out :) i took your toggleClass out and replace w/ .addClass('active').siblings("li").removeClass('active');

Comment: Sorry I was away, glad you did it!

Comment: roXon, i'm trying the fancy DEMO 3 :) Could you please show me how to make the bg stick instead of fadeOut when you mouseOut from those <li> ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#listchart li").mouseover(function(){
    var newclass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#piechart').attr('class', 'piechart-' + newclass);
});
```

Comment: Neil, no need to copy/modify/paste codes. You could just comment my answer and suggest the OP.

Comment: roXon, sorry I didn't see your answer before I submitted mine - you beat me to it - and rather than leave incorrect code as an answer I thought I'd better fix it. Regards

Comment: I apologize Neil! I even looked at you profile and your page and I must say I appretiate your work. Regards to you too, and happy coding! P.S. hope next time you're gonna be the one to beat me! ;)